# Order by two tables in node orm2 with an order by between them

Tags: node.js, postgresql, join

I have this definition of table categories with node-orm2:

```
models.categories = db.define("categories", { 
  id: {type: 'serial', key: true}, 
  name: {type: 'text', required: true, unique:true}
}, {
  methods: {},
  validations: {}
});
```

And this definition of table products, which is related with categories:

```
models.products = db.define("products", { 
  id: {type: 'serial', key: true}, 
  description: {type: 'text', required: true}
}, {
  methods: {},
  validations: {}
}); 
models.products.hasOne("category", models.categories, {required: true, reverse: "products"});
```

I've tried to get all categories and its related products to make a report with a control break on category name and product description, something like this:

```
select *
from categories cat,products prod
where cat.id = prod.category_id
order by cat.name, prod.description;
```

But I couldn't find a clear way to make that 'order by'. I've defined a async procedure to get all categories, and after that, for each category, all products ordered. Of course, its very slow. How I can get all with a single query ?